# Critique my workout routine

Tags: workout-routines, strength, strength-training, high-intensity

I workout on a 4 days cycle:

All are 2 sets for 6-8 reps.

Day 1, chest and triceps;

- 1x dumbell press warm up set (70% weight of working sets)
- flat dumbell press
- upper chest focused converging press
- pec deck flys
- barbel skull crushers
- straight bar push downs

Day 2, back and biceps;

- narrow grip pull downs
- straight arm pull downs
- barbell rows
- back flys
- barbell curls
- alternating dumbell hammer curls

Day 3, shoulders and legs;

- dumbell overhead press
- lateral raises
- rear delt flys
- quad focused leg press
- dumbell RDL's
- calf raises

Day 4 - REST

Repeat...

I've been training seriously for almost 3 years. I've been using this low volume, high intensity routine for almost 12 months now and it did raise my number quite well but I've reached a bit of a plateau again recently. I'm just wondering if anyone has any ways to improve my routine.

Comment: The first thing I look for in questions like this is leg stuff. Specifically deadlifts and/or squats. Unless you have a very particular reason not to do them, they belong in every routine. You have 3 leg exercises, but they are all what we'd call supplementary exercises. If you haven't squatted or deadlifted a lot over the 3 years you've been training, it's pretty much guaranteed to break your plateau. Beyond that, I have some gripes with any routine that repeats the same set of exercises week after week. Variation is key to overcoming plateaus.

Comment: @Alecisonstrike I chose the leg exercises I that I did because if I added squats and traditional deadlifts I would be at 5 leg exercises which would kind of be avoiding my whole low volume method.

Comment: Also the plateau I was referring to is mainly with my chest exercises. And I do vary it slightly by changing between dumbell, barbell and machine presses and alternating between pec deck and dumbell flys. In general though I keep my routine simple by doing a flat press and upper chest press and a fly.

Comment: Additional details should be edited into the original question. As for the leg exercises; if you want a low number of exercises, then you should outright remove the ones you have and *replace them* with squats and deadlifts.